# Xcode 7.1 - Prototype cells in storyboard not showing up

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I just updated to Xcode 7.1 and I noticed that all of the prototype cells in my storyboard tableviews are showing as blank and their elements are missing. Sometimes I can see the prototype cells at the top of the tableview, but when I scroll down to view the others all the cells appear blank and white again.

Has anybody else experienced this and is there a quick fix?

Comment: That sounds annoying (to say the least). Does the app run okay?

Comment: Yeah that app runs fine, it's just the storyboard interface that's acting up

Comment: I would suggest taking some screen shots and filing a bug report with Apple. :(

Comment: I have a similar issue with static tableviews that started today. For any cell that is outside of the simulated size when the storyboard loads, the elements don't become visible when I scroll the tableview. The elements are still there, just not visible. If I change the VC to a larger simulated size the problem remains consistent, meaning that new cells become visible, but not all. No problem when running the app, only in the storyboard.

Comment: @blwinters I'm running into the exact same issue. Have you found a work around?

Comment: @blwinters I found a temporary workaround. If you download Xcode 6.4 this might unblock you. It worked for me. Feasibility of this solution depends on how much your application relies on iOS 9 features (mine doesn't). Xcode 6.4 has app signing issues if you need to upload to iTunesConnect, but there are workarounds for this.

Comment: I filed a bug report w/ Apple. Yeah I had to roll back to Xcode 7.0.1 to get the cells working again. Hopefully they fix this soon. Have noticed a huge dip in the quality of their software on iOS and OSX lately :/

Comment: Seems they fixed it in 7.1.1

Comment: Please drag edited table cell to up. Where it is visible. Repeat with other cells. Little trick )

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'm also experiencing this issue.

As a quick workaround, you can set the View Controller simulated size to Freeform, and make it big enough to accomodate all of your custom cells.

[Select View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxTqh.png)

[Change its height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6B10.png)

Changing it back to Fixed will revert it to the regular size.

Comment: I guess its not fixed. I am still experiencing the issue in 7.1.1

Comment: I'm still seeing it in 7.2 as well. This did help me work around it though

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the Table View and selecting the 'size inspector' icon in the 'utilities' pane and ticking the checkbox 'Preserve SuperView Margins' in the 'view' section seems to reset it.

[preserve superview margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw3fr.png)

However it's not fixing the problem, it worked fine in previous versions and I agree with @matt to file a bug report with Apple

Edited: Seems they fixed it in 7.1.1

[image: xcode 7.1.1]

Comment: Seems they fixed it in 7.1.1

Comment: I updated XCode and the problems seems to be **UN**solved.

Comment: @raistlin make sure you have 7.1.1 and restart xcode, for me it's working fine. The update also mentions the bug is solved.